# Is it possible to get accessToken on behalf of user's RefreshToken?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api

In my web application I have integrated user Firebase Authentication using Google Sign-in. After successful sign-in Firebase returns AccessToken and RefreshToken. Using this AccessToken I am able to call Google APIs (eg; calendar API).

What I wanted to know: If I store user's RefreshToken in DB, later on (may be after a week or so) application backend can get user's RefreshToken from DB and call some Google API (don't know which and how) to retrieve user's AccessToken. This AccessToken will be used to call Google APIs without any issue.

In short, is it possible for backend to retrieve user's AccessToken by using user's RefreshToken for calling Google APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant say i have tried with something that came from firebase auth but in theory it should work

This is the call you make.

```
HTTP POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=[REFRESHTOKEN]&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Love to hear if it works or not.

Comment: Unfortunately not and throws below error:
```{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}```

Comment: refresh token may be expired authorize the user again, or check the date on your machine it needs to be in sync with NTP

Comment: I see one difference in refreshToken returned by Firebase and Google Playground.

Firebase returns long string like `AOEOulaw0L2j_BRkRlkAiAyuSk-iS94apB7KH-ihtiW72gzwgy9xB4QNkS8kR1YunBYGkEo6Ig7Lpfa4GASdfweOPFByrH5kZPKyjry0I0W2EInUg0Yf2H25wlPO6kra9v35enw1YZaCfokYrt5JvrgIYFlm61GQ5JDu7dxDtqQ9JIHcxRhTfSzdyrC5lLjrb05fLWnacELLgW7pICvDBAymvSx.....` while Google Playground return short string RefreshToken like `1//04KyK8ikE2Sw1CgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9Ir1LYK8Ppt637nkBIXeL_AuMgqJPI5H1atAsQDP63qvcl7yV2f6BxHuyX-1hZIVP_xcro`

I think this is the major issue why your suggestion not working.

Comment: You understand that firebase and google apis are two different systems.  What makes you think the refresh token for one will work with the other?

Comment: It was my bad @daimto Confusion started when Firebase returns OAuth AccessToken which can be utilised to call Google APIs without any problem.

Comment: I cant say i have used firebase much.  But i do know that firebase auth and google auth are two different systems.  Im not sure they can be mixed in this manner.   If you have a firebase refresh token then you would probably need to send it to the firebase authorization server in order to get a new access token back.